# android Api key not found for api < 21

Tags: android

i have been building an app uses google maps api and every thing is ok for api >= 21.
in manifest i put:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

although these lines exists for api < 21 this error was shown:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

any help please

Answer (score 0):

to any one face the same problem, here is the solution:
android studio generates the google_maps_api.xml file in values-v21 folder.
you have to copy this file and paste it in the default folder values.